# Specification with Spring JPA not applying the clauses mentioned

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0

I have a requirement for building a dynamic query based on filter. I have an Array which contain the filter criteria based on the entries in the Array I am building the Predicate. But with my current implementation its like the spec is not getting passed to the findall query. The response I am getting has all the data. Could someone correct me if something is missing or wrong.

My Repository interface

```java
@Repository
public interface Company extends JpaRepository<Comp, Integer>{
    List<Comp> findAll(Specification spec);
}
```

My Spec builder

```java
private Specification specificationOnFilter(List<Filter> filters) {
    new Specification<Comp>() {
        @Override
        Predicate toPredicate(Root<Comp> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            // Building predicate, adding into the predicates object
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        }
    };
}
```

My final call is like below

```java
MyRepository.findAll(specificationOnFilter(filter));
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>(); // Building predicate, adding into the predicates object
return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
```

Seem's to just generate predicate from empty ArrayList of predicate's. Therefore your final predicate will pass all the data since it doesn't contain it was builded from zero predicates.

```
predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]) // will be empty in your case.
```

You should involve `List<Filter> filter` from argument of your method and build predicates `List<Predicate>` from it instead of just creating `new ArrayList<>()` which is empty.

Also in your question you don't provide any information on what libraries you are using. What are `Filter` and `Specification` and `Scope` classes (this comes from spring cloud i guess). Therefore it's hard to reproduce issue and you will be provided with abstract answer's.

Comment: The mistake was at my end, everytime I was adding an empty object to the predicates list and the object having the actual predicate was just getting overwritten in the loop and never actually passed to the predicate list.